# Textlabel in a table cell exceeding into detail text

Tags: uitableview, ios4

I created a table with Value 1 cell style. Since almost all (main) text labels are rather long, I did

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

on all its cells and increased rows' height. Now, when the (main) text would exceed the width of the *whole* row, it wraps into 2 lines and it is OK (see the middle row in my screenshot). However, when the text is shorter, it does not wrap at all, even if it exceeds its area and leaves little or no space for the detailed text (see the other rows -- the detail text is set to "12345 Kč" in *every* cell). I want the texts in these cells to be wrapped into 2 lines if they will left little space for detail texts otherwise. I do not want to resize fonts or shorten texts -- there *is* enough space for texts in rows. Do you know any simple solution? (I do not like to create special labels etc. if it is not necessary.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly, I did not find a simple solution (e.g. setting of a property) even in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html). So I had to create my own label, but I made use of the original cell as much as possible (e.g. I used `detailTextLabel`) and tried to design my label as close to the original as possible. Here is my code:

```
#define MASTER_LABEL_TAG 100

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *masterLabel;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        masterLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 8.0, 195.0, 48.0)];
        masterLabel.tag = MASTER_LABEL_TAG;
        masterLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
        masterLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];
        masterLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:masterLabel];
    }
    else
    {
        masterLabel = (UILabel *) [cell.contentView viewWithTag:MASTER_LABEL_TAG];
    }
    masterLabel.text = @"Something goes here";
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps even someone else.